# How useful is C for working as embedded engineer?

Tags: c, embedded

I have finished a course of basic C programming and I wonder is C useful/powerful for working as embedded engineer, should I spend a lot of time to master it or should I move to a higher programming language?

And if it is useful, as I want to work as embedded engineer, can you advise me what aspects should I learn/practice more about C (like pointer or array, driver...) so it can become a useful skill for my future?

Comment: As an engineer doing embedded microcontollers, you will spend a lot of time working with C or assembly language.  Higher level languages are generally a bad match for the restricted resources a microcontroller has available.

Comment: That said, this question doesn't really fit this site.

Comment: You would not need very much time to master C if you know basic C. C# and C++ is much more complex than C.

Comment: "C# and C++ is much more complex than C" - I'd disagree with regards to C#. It's a language for a completely different purpose, but it's no more complex really. While there are more advanced topics to be found in C#, if anything it's less complex in terms of the code you actually write due to the vast amount of functionality available in the .NET framework. Still irrelevant to embedded for the most part (aside from .NET Micro)

Comment: Embedded systems are, historically, largely written in C, but there are more modern frameworks and environments which suit less performance- and memory-critical platforms. The most obvious example is the Arduino framework, which is C++ based, and in fact a large amount of AVR platform code is written in C++. Another example is MicroPython, which is favoured largely by hobbyists, though I've seen it in use on at least one production design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, almost all embedded programming is done in C.  I find knowledge of bitwise manipulation is the main thing that is important compared to C used for programming other types of applications.

C is considered very useful and powerful for embedded work because it is low level enough that it compiles easily to machine language, and yet is still high level enough to be readable, easily understood by many other developers (if you do it well), and give access to abstract data types.

Comment: So which aspect of C should I learn/master more? (for example pointer, data structure, bitwise, or write the system/driver???)

Comment: I think the most important skill you will need to use is creating bitwise conditionals and bitwise manipulation, as I noted.  You could do a lot without creating custom types or using pointer, but it's very difficult to get by without a solid understanding of bitwise operations, unless you use a lot of abstraction (e.g. Arduino libraries for GPIO), but it's better to understand how to do this by grass roots in C.  Once that's second-nature for you, get a good understanding of structs, typedefs, enums, etc.

Comment: Then learn pointers.  This can take a while to assimilate fully, but once you do it is an extremely powerful tool when writing C firmware.  It can drastically improve code performance and resource efficiency.  Writing system drivers is good to understand but can be rather complicated and most embedded development doesn't need to enter that area.  I would focus on the others first.

Answer (score -4):

The 'c' and 'c++' language are the most useful languages for embedded systems in my opinion. You should learn everything about 'c' and 'c++'. The next step could be learning a scripting language such as LUA.

Comment: C, yes. The others, abolutely not! Embedded systems typically don't have the memory available to run them or the resources to run scripted languages.

Comment: Wait 5 years, you will see. At this moment the microPython is for embedded systems. An embedded system can also be a IoT device running some kind of operating system.

Comment: @Jot The same was said when I studied in 1999. "C will be gone in a few years, all microcontrollers will get programmed in Java". Some schools even stopped teaching embedded C programming in favour of "embedded Java", whatever that was. It was all a hype created by PC programmers - the use of Java in embedded systems died completely a few years later. Also, any language which requires _another_ language  underneath it, will always fail to replace C. So you can probably forget all about Python.

Comment: Sorry, but you have not convinced me. I would call ESP8266 inside a device also a embedded system. The same for an Cortex M0+. That is the way we are going. I think that 'c' will be with us for a very long time, but 'c++' is no problem.